# I need to filter the yui datatable which has inline cell editing. and the data is coming from the groovy controller in key:value pair form. as JSON

Tags: grails

hi i am also facing the data error problem. i wanted to filter the data coming from json result from the groovy controller in key:value pair. even if i chage the TYPE_JSON to TYPE_JSARRAY,i am getting NoRecordas found in data table but the json result has the data.

please can u correct me.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

```
dobMenuButton.subscribe("selectedMenuItemChange",function(e) {
    var value =e.newValue.value;
    if(YAHOO.lang.isValue(value)) {
        myDataTable.getDataSource().sendRequest(null, {
            success:function(request, response, payload) {
                this.initializeTable();
                var rs = response.results;
                var filtered = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < rs.length; i++) {
                    if(((rs[i].dateOfBirth).format("MM/dd/yyyy")) == value) {
                        filtered[filtered.length] = rs[i];
                    }
                }
                this.getRecordSet().reset();                                                 
                MCMPagination.paginatorvar.setTotalRecords(filtered.length,true);
                this.getRecordSet().setRecords(filtered, 0);
                this.render();
        },
        scope:myDataTable, 
            argument:myDataTable.getState()
        });
    }
});
```